# Timezone is changed from winter to summer rails shows timestamp according to new time zone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a case my user was created in winter time zone at 19:56 and now the timezone of the country is changed and it shows me that It was created at 20:56 I want to show the actual time of according to winter time zone as it was created at 19:56. what I need to do how can I handle the winter and summer timezones in my rails application so that it should show actual time according to timezone when it was created.

Comment: what is the type of your data?

Comment: its datetime @lau

Comment: timestamp? with or without time zone? and another question "when you say the timestamp of the country has changed", would you have timestamps to be expressed in several countries?

Comment: Yes application is running in multiple different servers.

Comment: As I expected, I can not simply reproduce that in postgresql, I suspect it comes from your rail application. Can you copy paste exactly what you get when you `select` the create date/time for that user, directly from the DB (not from your rail app)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the code you want the timezone of your need. It is as simple as the following example:

```
SELECT yourtimevariable AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' FROM yourtable;
```

More information regarding the topic:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-datetime.html